# Batch - "Echo is on" appearing sometimes... whats the cure?

Tags: batch-file, echo

Why is "ECHO is off" appearing here and ruining everything?

**Source Code:**

```
set authfile=\\COMPUTER\Users\username\auth.txt
echo Authentication file not detected.
echo.
echo Press enter to generate a new one...
pause > nul
echo 4.7>"%authfile%"
echo 0>>"%authfile%"
echo sigh>>"%authfile%"
echo 0>>"%authfile%"
echo 0>>"%authfile%"
echo 0>>"%authfile%"
echo 0>>"%authfile%"
echo 0>>"%authfile%"
if exist "%authfile%" goto success
goto failure
```

**Output:**

```
Authentication file not detected.

Press enter to generate a new one...
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

**auth.txt:**

```
4.7
sigh
```

Yes, those all 0's must be outputted in the right order and place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0>>` means you're trying to [redirect](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) file descriptor 0 (i.e. STDIN) to the output file. Either put the redirection at the beginning of the line, as [Endoro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18171572/1630171) suggested:

```
>>"%authfile%" echo 0
```

or escape the number:

```
echo ^0>>"%authfile%"
```

Answer (score 3):

put the `echo` command behind the redirection:

```
>"%authfile%" echo 4.7
>>"%authfile%" echo 0
...
```

Answer (score 3):

The cause of your six "ECHO is off" messages is due to your writing the following line:

```
echo 0>>"%authfile%"
```

The correct form of this statement is (note the space between the "0" and the ">>"):

```
echo 0 >>"%authfile%"
```

**Technical Explanation**

The error lies in DOS batch language redirection syntax.  You can redirect output to either *stdout* or *stderr* by using the numbers 1 or 2, respectively:

```
echo Hi! 1>"%authfile%"
echo Hi! 2>"%authfile%"
```

Because you left out the space in your case, DOS parsed the "0" as the redirection number, where 0 corresponds to *stdin*.  Since piping to *stdin* does not make sense, the DOS batch parser ignored the piping, leaving you with:

```
echo
```

Without the '.' after echo, you will get the message "ECHO is off.".

Comment: `2>` redirects STDERR to a file. It does not redirect output *to* STDERR (that would be `>&2`). Also `CMD.exe` doesn't have anything to do with DOS. And putting a space between number and redirection operator would produce lines with a trailing space.